# How to update the textbox value without page refresh using ajax in mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i want to update the texbox value from database without page refresh. I tried to update the textbox value without page refresh it updating the value without page refresh but it not correctly bind to that textbox.

**My Controller**

```
    public ActionResult PageRefresh()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetDateTime()
    {
        var date = db.SYNCs.Select(e => new { currentdataimport = e.SDT }).FirstOrDefault();
        var currentDataimporttime = date.currentdataimport;
        var finalvalue = new { success = true, time = currentDataimporttime.ToString() };
        return Json(finalvalue,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My View Code**

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td id="Refreshtable">
        <input type="text" id="Dateimporttime" />
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetDateTime","Page")',
         datatype: "Json",
         success: function (data) {
             $("#Dateimporttime").val(data.time)
             }
         });
      });
     </script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
    setInterval(function () {  $('#Refreshtable').load('/Page/GetDateTime'); }, 50000),
        $("#Dateimporttime").val(data.time)
});
</script>
```

Here first i load the textbox value using ajax. Then i set the reload function for that particular table especailly textbox.Then again i load the recent value which is in db to that textbox.

But its not updating the value in textbox.it updating the value but not binding in that textbox. Any one tell me what mistake i did and correct my mistake. I tried my level best to explain the issue. Any one understand my issue and give me solution for my problem.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: you want to refresh the date after 5 seconds?

Comment: No I need at least 15to 30mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script should be like this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     new updatedate(); 
   });

     function updatedate () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetDateTime","Page")',
         datatype: "Json",
         success: function (data) {
             $("#Dateimporttime").val(data.time);
             setTimeout(function(){updatedate();}, 15 * 60 * 1000);

             }
         });
      };
     </script>
```

what i am doing here is i created a function named `updatedate` which gets the date from json and populate it in the `textbox` then i used set timeout on success that after first time it goes to success it will set the value and set the `setTimeout` which means it will recall `updatedate` after 5 seconds (you can increase the time)

Comment: Can you explain your code and let me know have to change anything in text boc code. because u used updatedate function so i lightly confused can you explain your code ??

Comment: ok i have a try and let you know then how to set 15 to 30 min

Comment: its working but for single load it iterate json function which i wrote in controller for 2 to 3 times . after loading 2 to 3 times it return to view why??